# I want to upload image on twitter using twitter4j in android

Tags: android, twitter4j

while uploading an image on twitter using twitter4j, it works good for all the mobiles excepts Lollipop versions.
Can you please help me, I am using AsyncTask for it

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationbuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationbuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
        configurationbuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(twitter_consumer_key);
        configurationbuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitter_secret_key);
        configurationbuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(token);
        configurationbuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(secret);
        configurationbuilder.setMediaProviderAPIKey(twitpic_api_key);
        twitter4j.conf.Configuration configuration = configurationbuilder
                .build();

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();
    //  Log.d("ImageUploader", "Start sending image...");
        try {
            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(editTweet.getText()
                    .toString());
            status.setMedia(new File(mPath));
            twitter.updateStatus(status);
            // url = imageupload.upload(new File(mPath));
            //result = 1;
            //System.out.println("URL Is : " + url);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getStatusCode();
            e.getCause();
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

but it didn't upload any image on twitter while i am using this for lollipop version

Comment: What do you expect the calls in you catch block to do?

Comment: Trying to get all the details like status code, why it gives an exception and message, catch only called when i am using lollipop version

Comment: Actually I know what you're trying to do - but what you wrote (apart from `printStackTrace`) doesn't produce any output, does it?

Comment: yup it doesn't work..But my actual problem is to upload image using twitter4j from lollipop version which doesn't work

Comment: So can you help me with that?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you told us what error you get? Did you debug? Where does the error occur? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I got error at status.setMedia(new File(mPath)); It gives me Null Object Reference error

Comment: I can not see how you retrieve `mPath` in your code. You need to debug and find out exactly what is null - `mPath` or `status`.

Comment: Well, I think I've said everything there is to say: Debug, check what's causing the null reference exception and then come back here.

Comment: Already solved the problem..Thank you @ThorstenDittmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API >= 19 Use this code

```
private String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context,
        Uri mImageCaptureUri2) {
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(mImageCaptureUri2);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel,
            new String[] { id }, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

For API < 19 Use this code

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return null;

    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```